# Page is jittering when doing mouse scroll

Tags: jquery

I am scrolling page when there is a hash value on URL. What happening is after click on any service its going to a page and then when click back it just scroll to service section.

Now the issue is, is jquery scroll and mouse scroll both are scrolling simultaneously the page is jittering.

Video: https://viakode.com/luke/Screen%20shaking.m4v

So is there any solution for that.

```
$(window).load(function () {
    var hash = window.location.hash;
    $('.navbar-nav li a').each(function () {
        if (hash === $(this).attr('href')) {
            $(this).click();
        }
    });
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('body').css('pointer-events', 'all');
    }, 1000);
})
```

Comment: provide HTML and required CSS also

Comment: http://viakode.com/luke/     here you can see source code.

Comment: this is an external website, please provide the link either in form of fiddle, or as stackoverflow snippet.